# Add event listeners directly to a createElement() object VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, createelement

Im trying to create an object with event listeners and property values in vuejs and i fount that way

```
let nouveauItem = document.createElement(this.itemToCreate, {
                on: { 
                    dragover: this.dragOver,
                    dragenter: this.dragEnter,
                    dragleave: this.dragLeave,
                    drop: this.dragDrop
                }
            })
```

but it doesnt seem to work, is it still available in vue 2 ?
I know i can just add addEventListeners but i wanted to make it clear.
I tried with a simple function as well, eg.

```
click: () => { console.log("hello") }
```

Comment: Where did you find that? The `document` API is not part of VueJS, it's a browser API. Now, you can do that kind of thing with jQuery, but jQuery also isn't VueJS.

Comment: You could use render function is vue way

Comment: hm ok but render is used to display a component, isn't it ? I want to create new tags (on button click for example). I though i could use document.createElement to make it in vue